# Windows 7 search for files with special characters in name

Tags: windows-7, search

I have a rather large source code repository on my machine; it is not indexed by Windows Search.  I am trying to find some oddly-named generated files of the form `.#name.extension.version` where name and extension are normal names and extensions and version is a numeric value (e.g. something like 1.186).  On Windows XP I could find these files by searching for `.#*`; on Windows 7 that just returns every single file and directory.  So my question is this: is it possible to find files named like that using the built-in Windows 7 search functionality?

I did find [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/172522/windows-7-search-for-file-with-a-special-character-in-the-file-name) which is very similar, but the answer doesn't work for me; it seems like any special character I put in the query is either ignored or treated as a wildcard, and as a result it matches every single file and directory.

Is there perhaps some registry value I can set to make the search-by-filename feature work with special characters?

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Answer (score 1):

Doh, I stumbled upon the answer after consulting the [Advanced Query Syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx) reference again.  Searching for `filename:.#*` gives me the XP search behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/how-to-search-for-special-characters-in-explorer/8e223aef-3240-4a16-aa79-e9562f97858f?auth=1

This makes me think that the star character ("*") is the escape character for special characters in Windows Advanced Query Syntax and that it comes BEFORE the special character.

I tried it and found that #* doesn't work but that *# DOES work. I think the other answerer might have gotten this backwards.