# How to search for a quotation mark in file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I need to find a cs file in file explorer that contains .load(" but I'm not sure how to search for a quotation mark in file explorer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 search for file with a special character in the file name?](https://superuser.com/questions/172522/windows-7-search-for-file-with-a-special-character-in-the-file-name)

However, works for **file content** as well if you escape `"` a double quote *by doubling it* as follows:

```
~=".load("""
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how-to combine this literal search with wildcards.