# How to search for a quotation mark in windows search file explorer

Tags: windows, search, file-search

I'm trying to filter out search results in windows explorer, in such a way that it should retrieve only the files containing a " character.

e.g.
Document 001 "sendto" jane.pdf

I've tried:

- "
- ~="
- ~="""

Also found promising threads but no one could answer this particular character.

[How to search for a quotation mark in file explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1137157/how-to-search-for-a-quotation-mark-in-file-explorer)

[Windows 7 search for file with a special character in the file name?](https://superuser.com/questions/172522/windows-7-search-for-file-with-a-special-character-in-the-file-name)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I found the problem.

In windows the regular quotation mark character is not allowed.

If we create a new file and input " in the file name it will block it.

[image]

However, I downloaded some emails into a folder and it uses a special/different quotation character.

I placed the mouse cursor over that character and copied it (ctrl+c) and I was able to use it freely.

I was then able to use the following filter

~="“"