# search for file name within a file

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to use the Windows 7 search to look for a file name within a file like this:

```
content:"reports.asp"
```

Instead of getting just files that contains "reports.asp" I am also getting files that contains "reports". I have also tried this because I thought I have to escape the character:

```
content:"reports\.asp"
```

How can I modify my search so that I am only getting files that contains "reports.asp"?

[UPDATE] I have checked [Trouble trying to use Windows Search to search for file with a question mark in the content](https://superuser.com/questions/168638/trouble-trying-to-use-windows-search-to-search-for-file-with-a-question-mark-in) and it appears that it did not help me. I have tried using the suggestion as follows:

```
content:"reports~=.asp"
```

But I get the same result as if I just used my first search parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

### Using the FIND command in CMD

Ended up solving the problem using FIND.

`FIND /I "reports.asp" C:\Approximate location of file\*`

*Note that you must include the asterisk * as you are searching for a file not folder. Failing to do so will yield an **Access is Denied** error.

### The method below is for searches not wanting to find content inside files (so only for file names)

Open **Folder Options** by going into **Control Panel,** clicking **Appearance and Personalization,** and then clicking **Folder Options** (or any of the numerous other ways to get there).

[image]

Under the **Search** tab, disable **Find Partial Matches**. This should fix your problem.

[image]

Comment: It did not help :(. I'm still getting files that are not including reports.asp but are including reports or asp.

Comment: Have you tried search **without** `content:`? Using that searches inside files. http://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-on-windows-7

Comment: I want to search for a file name within files so I need to use `content:`, unless there is something else that I can use. Just searching for reports.asp returns the reports.asp which is what I do not want.

Comment: @JohnOdom do you know the file type of the file? And is this a one-time search?

Comment: I do not know the file types of the files that may contain that string, and it is a one-time search. I wanted to search for it so that I would not have to open up each file manually to look for files that reference reports.asp.

Comment: Just an idea, what happens if you put `content: ""reports.asp""`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18943/discussion-between-john-odom-and-rsya-studios).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm going to be using this more when I need to look for file references in an unknown directory :).

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use file commander for this, for example [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/). You can search then in selected files, within them and archives like rar, zip etc. inside. You can even search for a particular regular expression then!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would prefer a solution that does not require me to download anything since I'm not allowed to download/install anything myself on this PC.

Comment: Then you can use cmd.exe and tools provided as 'find' and 'for'.